# Pass return value from .aspx.cs method to .apsx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get my project done, but i'm stuck.

All I want to do is pass on my method-return value to the .aspx as regular text.

```
[WebMethod]
public static String VerySimpleStuff() {
     return "Hello";
}
```

within the `.aspx` file i want to call this very simple method now.

`<%=namesp._Default.VerySimpleStuff()%>`

yet i'm not able to display the text. please help me.

Comment: only remove [WebMethod] & check the namespace,classname is correct .

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right,only problem with this is you are unnecessarily using `[WebMethod]` attribute.Just remove `[WebMethod]` attribute and your code will work.

Webmethods in code behind are used for AJAX calls,that is not your requirement.